# urllib2 authentication will not return whether it was successful or not

Tags: python, authentication, python-2.7, urllib2, autologin

I am using minecraft.net as an example:

- When I type http://minecraft.net/login, it always comes back as "Password Found" and
- When I type http://minecraft.net/login.php, it always comes back as "Login Failed"

I have also tried (https ://www.facebook.com/login.php) and
(https ://www.facebook.com/login.php) .

My goal is for the code to tell me whether the password is correct or incorrect (Obviously).

Is it the link I'm typing or is it my code? If it is my code, what am I doing wrong? I've tried many different scripts.

Code that works is appreciated but I am completely ok with you telling me how to fix this!

```
import urllib2
import os
os.system("color 09")
print "URL To Login To: "
URL = raw_input("> ")
os.system("cls")
print "User Name To Login With: "
username = raw_input("> ")
os.system("cls")
print "Password As Test: "
password = raw_input("> ")
os.system("cls")

import urllib2, base64

request = urllib2.Request(URL)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
try:
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    print "Password Recovered: " + password
except:
    print "Login Failed: "
```

Comment: That website doesn't use this kind of authorization. You need to send a POST request to `/login` and the server will respond with an HTML page. I'm sure there's some sort of API for this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because reproducing this problem requires users to attempt to gain unauthorized access to a system.

Comment: Note: If all you actually want to do is login to such a service via Python, you should not use the word brute, which suggests you're attempting to [brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) into it - if that actually _is_ your intend, you're not welcome here

Comment: Oh i'm sorry! I used bad wording, I did not mean brute as in hack, i meant Brute as in "To get into" Not hack, i'm sorry for the misunderstanding, 
I need to gain access to my account via python, yes

Comment: @Windows65 I'm still not sure what you're ultimately trying to achieve, but you shouldn't mess around with logins like that. There usually exists an API to do this

Answer (score 2):

Your whole Password Found / Brute Failed logic is based on recieveing a valid HTTP response or not.

You get the Brute Failed message because that login.php page does not exist (thus returns a 404 error).

You get the password found for the other page because it does exist, and returns a valid HTTP response which is what urllib2 expects.

You are getting a valid HTTP response saying you have the wrong password, no doubt.

You need to always check for valid HTTP response, and then add further checks to see if you got a "Bad Password" or "Good Password" reply.  You do this by searching for your required text in the resonse body.